# Pyspark - How to sum columns when column contains specific string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Very new to `pyspark`.

I am trying to `sum` the columns that contain a specific string, in this case the string is "Cigarette volume". Assume my dataframe is called `df_company`

```
selected = [s for s in df_company.columns if 'Cigarette volume' in s]
selected

Out[66]: ['Cigarette volume south asia',
 'Cigarette volume latin america & caribbean',
 'Cigarette volume middle east & north africa',
 'Cigarette volume east asia & pacific',
 'Cigarette volume north america',
 'Cigarette volume sub saharan africa',
 'Cigarette volume europe & central asia',
 'Cigarette volume total']
```

The inefficient way would be to add them manually i.e.:

```
new = df_company.withColumn("Total cicarette volume", col("Cigarette volume europe & central asia")+col("Cigarette volume sub saharan africa")+col("Cigarette volume north america")+col("Cigarette volume east asia & pacific")+col("Cigarette volume middle east & north africa")+col("Cigarette volume latin america & caribbean")+col("Cigarette volume south asia"))
```

But I am looking for something more generic along the lines of getting the columns in a list, and summing them:

```
selected = [s for s in df_company.columns if 'Cigarette volume' in s]

new = df_company.withColumn('Cigarette volume total', sum(df_company[col] for col in selected))
new = df_company.withColumn('Cigarette volume total', sum(df_company.select(selected))
```

However, both attempts fail. Can anyone shed some light on how to sum the columns containing a specific string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sum(df_company[col] for col in selected)` should work. Did you do `from pyspark.sql.functions  import *` and overwrote the Python `sum` function?

Comment: that was a good point, which I just addressed. Now I am getting back the error ```TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1a57335ad0> of type <class 'generator'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.``` Does it matter if I have ```null``` in them?

Comment: still looks like you're using the spark sql sum...

Comment: I think I overwrote the Python ```sum``` function then. If I remove that line of code from that block, and rerun, will that do? Or do I have to restart kernel and not import?

Comment: yes, restarting is needed I think

Comment: common practice is doing `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` and call functions as `F.col` for example

Comment: This is a silly question but, if I run ```import pyspark.sql.functions as F``` in any code block I am overrunning python sum. So is there a way to revert back without restarting?

Comment: you can do `del sum`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your time and your explanation. I am happy to accept an answer from you if you want to post one. As there isn't another one on stackoverflow regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new = df_company.withColumn('Cigarette volume total', sum(df_company[col] for col in selected))
```

should work, but you have overwritten the Python builtin `sum` function with the Spark SQL equivalent. You can do `del sum` to get back the builtin `sum` function.

As a general good practice, `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` should be avoided. You can use something like `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` to prevent overwriting Python builtin functions with the same name (e.g. `sum`, `max`, `min`, `abs`, etc.)